# How to include milliseconds in Time.zone.parse method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I'm trying to get a Time object that includes milliseconds in its format:

```
x = Time.zone.parse("12-1-1998 00:00:00.000", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N")
```

I get an error when I add the format:

```
undefined method `year' for "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N":String (NoMethodError)
```

I also tried `Time.zone.parse("12-1-1998 00:00:00.000")`, but I get this:

```
1998-01-12T00:00:00Z
```

I need the time to look like this:

```
1998-01-12T00:00:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DateTime#strftime`](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime):

```
datetime = DateTime.strptime("2011-05-21 04:20:46.011", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L")
datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ")
 => "2011-05-21T04:20:46.011Z"
```

Comment: what about the `Z` at the end? also, there's no `T`, please look at the expected result. `1998-01-12T00:00:00.000Z`

Comment: @abdulahmad you can change the format string of `strftime` as per the need

Comment: `DateTime.strptime("2011-05-21 04:20:46.011", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L").strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ")`